# How to iterate within arrayList of object and get the result set by prefix matching?

Tags: java, string, collections, arraylist, iteration

I have the following class:

```
class A {
    String s;
}
```

And the following list of lists of `class A` objects:

```
[{1s, 3f, 46h}, {333s, 67b, 1d, 67m, 67h}, {3a, 3x}, {34n, 22o, 34s},
 {40f, 22x, 4m}... and so on]
```

All I need is to iterate through this list, get the results and push into another output arrayList. Now what would be included in the result arrayList:

```
1. Just skip those elements from the above input arrayList
   which have more than one String with same prefix(only the last character
   is the suffix here which will always be a single character alphabet; not digit).
   For example: from the above input arrayList the first element({1s, 3f, 46h}) 
   won't be skipped and will be pushed into the output arrayList
   as it doesn't have any String with the same prefix; as 1, 3 and 46 are different.
   But 2nd, 3rd and 4th elements will be skipped as they have matches
   (three prefixes with same 67 in 2nd element, two prefixes with same 3 in 3rd element
   and two prefixes with same 34 in 4th element).

   So, for the above input arrayList the output arrayList will be:
   [{1s, 3f, 46h}, {40f, 22x, 4m}]
```

Can anybody suggest me how can I do the above job in an easy and efficient way. Please give
some sample code if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: This is homework, isn't it? What have you done so far?

Comment: @VivinPaliath and rambo coder: Didn't start yet. But I was thinking of doing something this: iterate through all the elements of inner list and check like this- say first String is 99x; then, "99x".substring(0, "99x".length()-1) will give me the prefix and then I will push this prefix into another List. After getting all the prefixes in a List I am thinking of using a custom comparator over this new List to check if it has the same item more than one time, if so then skip that element from the main input arrayList.
Little bit clumsy! Isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I were writing tests for this, I would see that one of the things I need is to be able to determine the prefix.  Given an A with string "55p", the prefix should be "55".  Write a test for that.  Where does the prefix method belong?  Probably in the A class itself.  It should look something like:

```
public String prefix() {
    return ...;
}
```

Once you have that method, it's easy to iterate over all the A's in a list and determine if any of them have the same prefix.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I appreciate your thought and finally did the job.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

I have tried out a logic, i will be happy, if this works for you.

```
`ArrayList<A> arrList` = [{1s, 3f, 46h}, {333s, 67b,67m, 67h}, {3a, 3x}, {40f, 22x, 4m}... and so on]


 ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();

for ( A a: arrList){

        for(String s : a) {

             int[] temp = a.indexOf(s);

             if (temp > 1){

                break; // will break the immediate loop, NOT the Outer loop

             }

            else{
                     newList.add(s);

              }

      }


}
```